# 3 phase DC motor controlling without countroller

Tags: microcontroller, motor, control

is it possible to drive 3 phase DC motor without a controller? 
how can I do it? 
I want to drive motor without controller because it's delivery is expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean a 3-phase BLDC motor? Maybe.  Just hook it up to a 3-phase AC source and it should run at synchronous speed.  Starting torque might not be great, and it will only run at one speed but there's no controller involved assuming you have an AC source with the proper voltage and frequency for the motor.

You might be able to generate the AC by using a second identical motor as a generator, running the shaft with a conventional brush motor hooked to a variable DC source.

Of course neither of those options is very attractive, so you're better off just getting or building a BLDC controller.